# Symfony form collection event->getData() return null

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

For a form I need a collection of entities, so use another form that using the prototype allows me to add and remove ellements.

The problem is that I need the symfony prototype for the generation of my new ones, but when I have "prototype = true" then event-> getData () returns null each time.

in the general form :

```
->add('profils', CollectionType::class, 
  array('entry_options' => ['entity_manager' => $this->em], 
  'entry_type' => ProfilType::class, 
  'prototype' => true, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true))
```

profilType (sub form) :

```
class ProfilType extends AbstractType {
    private $em;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $this->em = $options['entity_manager'];

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
    }


    protected function addElement(FormInterface $form, Domaine $domaine = null) {
        $form->add('fkDomaine', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PDFRecrutementBundle:Domaine',
            'choice_label' => 'doLibelle',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Domaine',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'select-domaine'
            )
        ));

        $sousDomaines = array();
        if ($domaine) {
            $repoSousDomaine = $this->em->getRepository('PDFRecrutementBundle:Sousdomaine');

            $sousDomaines = $repoSousDomaine->createQueryBuilder("q")
                    ->where('q.fkDomaine = :domaineId')
                    ->setParameter('domaineId', $domaine->getDoId())
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
        }

        $form->add('fkSousDomaine', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PDFRecrutementBundle:Sousdomaine',
            'choice_label' => 'sdLibelle',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $sousDomaines,
            'placeholder' => 'Sous domaine',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'select-sousdomaine'
            )
        ));
    }

    function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $domaine = $data->getFkDomaine() ? $data->getFkDomaine() : null;
            $this->addElement($form, $domaine);
    }

    function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            $domaine = $this->em->getRepository('PDFRecrutementBundle:Domaine')->find($data['fkDomaine']);
            $this->addElement($form, $domaine);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PDF\RecrutementBundle\Entity\Profil'
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired('entity_manager');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'pdf_recrutementbundle_profil';
    }

}
```

If I leave prototype = true I get the error :

> Call to a member function on null

so i need to have prototype at true and event-> getData () which does not return null, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working exemple on one of our projects:

```
->add('subType', CollectionType::class, [
                    'entry_type' => MySubClassType::class,
                    'entry_options' => array ('label' => false),
                    'label' => 'Awesome label',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'prototype_name' => 0,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'hidden'
                    ]
                ]
```

And on twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.subtype.vars.prototype.text) }}
```

Even working this way, if there's no value for "subType", it will be null, so you have to control that value anyway...